# How to record problem records when deleting Table rows by『On Error』statement

Tags: vba

```
Sub FilterRows(Field As String, Values As Collection)
   Dim FinalRow As Long
   Dim KeepValue As Variant
   Dim Table As ListObject
   Dim TableRange As Range
   Dim i As Integer

   With Worksheets("原始資料")
      FinalRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
     
   On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
      Set Table = .ListObjects("Table1")
      Set TableRange = Table.Range
    
      For i = TableRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        For Each KeepValue In Values
            If Intersect(TableRange.Rows.Item(i), Table.ListColumns(Field).Range).Value <> 
             CStr(KeepValue) Then
               TableRange.Rows.Item(i).Delete
            End If
        Next KeepValue
     Next
    
End With
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Number; ":" & Err.Description

    If Table Is Nothing Then
      Worksheets("原始資料").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Worksheets("原始資料").Range("A1:AK" & 
      FinalRow), , xlYes).Name = "Table1"
      Set Table = Worksheets("原始資料").ListObjects("Table1")
    Else
      Debug.Print "Error Record ID:" & Intersect(TableRange.Rows.Item(i), 
      Table.ListColumns("Record ID").Range).Value<===I'm not able to do This Line...
    End If
 Resume Next
End Sub
```

Hi Folks,
the purpose of this code is to delete table row based on a condition.

Somehow I got Error in certain table rows in the process of deletion, and I would like to know which row is fail.so I wrote this line :
『Debug.Print "Error Record ID:" & Intersect(TableRange.Rows.Item(i), Table.ListColumns("Record ID").Range).Value』.

There may be variable scope issue but I don't know how to pass varaible to Errorhandler. Or there is another good way to achieve what I want to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While testing your code, it's usually a good idea not to let the error handler handle you problem but let the runtime engine stop immediately at the line throwing the error. You can achieve this by either comment out the line `On Error Goto`, or go to the VBA Options and select "Break on all errors" (in the General Tab).

Scope of variables is the whole subroutine, so that shoudn't be a problem.

You should use the error handler to catch only unexpected errors. The logic of defining the table if it doesn't exist should be done at the point where you assign the variable:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set Table = .ListObjects("Table1")
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
If table Is Nothing Then
    With Worksheets("原始資料")
        Set table = .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .Range("A1:AK" & FinalRow), , xlYes)
    End With
    table.Name = "Table1"
End If    
Set TableRange = Table.Range
```

I am almost sure your problematic row is 1: You cannot delete the header row of a table.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. The problem is deleting the header row of a table.
But I have little confuse about your answer. I'm not sure why you're saying that not to let error handler handle a problem, and let the runtime engine stop immediately at the line throwing the error. Because sometimes, I don't want to interrupting the process, I log the problematic data instead.

Comment: You missunderstood my intention: It's okay to have an error handler. Just disable it while you are still developing / debugging. When done and you are confident that the program is doing what it shoud, enable it.